# Regex to return single attribute from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript, can someone please help me with a pattern to match something in this string:

```
div style="display: none" key="ABC\jones" displaytext="Tom Jones"
```

My goal is to extract the value for key, in this case: `ABC\jones`

So, everything between

```
key="
```

and

```
"
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

something like:

```
/ key="([^"]*)"/
```

should match

the tailing `"` is for completeness so that it matches `key="..."` and not just `key="...`

As for how this is working, the normal characters are them selves, the `[^"]` defines a match group of all characters that are not `"` ( the `^` being not ). So this will match everything after a `key="` until it collides with a `"`. The `( )` capture the matched values for later recall.

Comment: +1 But `/ key="([^"]*)"/` (leading whitespace) should be considered. I'm not going to make the remark about all the trouble that HTML + regex is bound to give :)

Comment: It works; thanks very much. can you please help me understand how it works. By the way, it seems to also work without the last double quote character.

Comment: It works like this: ( ) is a capture group, * means repeat looking for characters inside the [] character group, ^" means "not speechmark" so it just keeps going until it hits the end ".

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just do this?

```
document.getElementById("my_div").getAttribute("key")
```

Comment: This will get the id of an element that is already in the DOM.  If you need to get it from an HTML string, the regex match method (above) is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = 'div style="display: none" key="ABC\jones" displaytext="Tom Jones"';

var start = str.indexOf('key="') + 'key="'.length;
var end = str.indexOf('"', start + 1);

var result = str.substring(start, end);
```

That works... Does it have to be using regex?

Comment: Again, `str.indexOf(' key="') + ' key="'.length`.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, but I'd like to use a regular expression :-)